# Android Google Maps not compatible with AVD 4.0.3

Tags: android, maps

I am trying to display google maps using the google map api on avd 4.0.3 (latest). However, it says no compatible AVD could be found. Does anyone know which versions would be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an AVD with Google APIs add-on https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/

Choose target = `Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 15` when creating the AVD.

Comment: This target isn't visible anymore using latest version of ADT and API level 17. I guess, google just moved these APIs from the SDK add-on to  google play services APK and a corresponding client library. I guess, they didn't want to get cut by OEMs like Samsung by them not choosing to update the platform's system image to include these add-ons.